Can we see perlocutionary acts as indirect illocutionary acts? Does the distinction actually makes sense?
The question of distinguishing types of linguistic acts (speech acts, illocutionary acts, and perlocutionary) has already been answered, but I wonder: can we not think of this distinction as a progressive refinement rather than an exclusionary categorisation?
I mean seeing speech acts as being the most general act of utterance of a proposition, illocutionary acts being a speech act with illocutionary force, and perlocutionary acts being indirect illocutionary acts.
Is this how people in the field think of these terms, or should I see them as distinct categories?
Regardless, in the context of language games and in general late Wittgenstein's view on language, it feels like these three terms collapse: how can we have speech acts without illocutionary force when the semantics are themselves defined from their contextual use? Wouldn't that mean that any meaningful speech act is illocutionary?
In the same way, I fail to see how to pick out the indirectness of perlocutionary acts in practice, and it seems to me, then, to only be a property of an a-posteriori analytical analysis, rather than of in-vivo speech acts themselves.

Locution, illocution and perlocution are all seen as aspects of speech acts, and all three are typically present to some extent, although one or another may dominate. That does not mean that the distinction collapses, we can distinguish aspects even if they never appear separately in practice. Literal meaning, intended effect and actual effect are sensible and clearly distinct aspects of speech.

Seeing them as potentially cohabiting aspects instead of distinct categories is indeed an interesting point. I wonder though, you seem to imply that illocutionary acts are to be assigned to intention and perlocutionary acts by effet, but is that characterization valid? Wouldn't the phrase "it sure is cold here" with the illocutionary force of intending to have John close the window be a perlocutionary act while still having clear intention of the illocutionary type?
